# neo4j find all friends who posted something I liked

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I want to find all the friends that posted something I liked. Why does this query return no rows but each clause by themselves returns something?

```
 match (start:Person)-[:LIKES]->(post:Post), (start)-[:FRIEND]->(person: Person), (person)-[:POSTED]->(post) return start, post, person
```

[image: profile01]
[image: profile02]

Comment: The query could be improved for performance, but it does seem to be a correct query, I'd expect correct results. Can you PROFILE the query and add the plan with all elements expanded? We want to see for which expansion the number of rows go to zero. My guess is that a relationship type or label isn't quite correct.

Comment: I've uploaded a plan. It seems the filter (which there is none) is filtering it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the query plans.

We can see that the rows drop to zero on the expansion of `(start)-[:FRIEND]->(person)`, so one of two things is happening: either :FRIEND isn't the actual relationship type (probably an issue of mismatched cases), or more likely, all the :FRIEND relationships present are in the opposite direction, incoming to the start node instead of outgoing.

For social graphs like these, since they're both :Person nodes, there isn't a way to tell which direction the relationship was created in, and when you query, the direction shouldn't matter, all that should matter is that a :FRIEND relationship exists.

Try removing the direction from the pattern here: `(start)-[:FRIEND]-(person: Person)` . Provided your relationship type is correct, that should get you the right results.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I would also combine the 3 patterns into a single long pattern. Doing this will ensure that it doesn't pull extra patterns that don't fit later patterns (get retrieved, then filtered out later). Here is what that Cypher would look like:

```
MATCH (start:Person)-[:LIKES]->(post:Post)<-[:POSTED]-(person: Person)
WHERE (start)-[:FRIEND]-(person)
RETURN start, post, person
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by

```
MATCH (me:Person)-[:FRIEND]-(friend:Person)-[:POSTED]->(post:Post)<-[:LIKES]-(me)
RETURN DISTINCT friend
```

To get the (friend:Person) nodes